# Kernel and Image of a Rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\theta$ a fixed point, I want to finde the Kernel and Image of a Rotation, i.e, I need to solve $$R_{\theta}x=0$$ and find vectors $b \in R^2$ such that $$R_{\theta}x=b$$ have a solution.

So my attempt is:
For Kernel,we have $$R_{\theta}x=0 \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 
cos \theta &-sin \theta \\
sin \theta &cos \theta \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 
x_1  \\
x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
cos \theta*x_1 -sin \theta*x_2 \\
sin \theta*x_1 +cos \theta*x_2 \end{bmatrix}=x_1 \begin{bmatrix} 
cos \theta \\
sin \theta\end{bmatrix} + x_2 \begin{bmatrix} 
-sin \theta \\
cos \theta \end{bmatrix}    = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Here I do not know how find the Kernel and Image of a Rotation.
If someone can help me please. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: have you learned about determinants yet?

Comment: Just think geometrically.  $R_\theta$ rotates by an angle $\theta$.  Which points in the plane get mapped to $0$ by that rotation?

Comment: Yes I have studied determinate, and for Geometrically it is difficult

Comment: @Knight if you have access to the determinant then the size of the kernel should be easy

Comment: [Here's](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Earth_Rotation_%28Nepal%2C_Himalayas%29.jpg) an image of stars rotating around the north pole.  Where would a star have to start to end up at the center of rotation (the vector zero)?

Comment: @Bobbie D Very nice image you have here !

Comment: But Did I need to compute the determinant of the rotation?

Comment: You do not *need* to compute the determinant of the rotation, but determinants are a very powerful tool to deal with such problems. Here the determinant is $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1 \neq 0$, thus $R_\theta$ is inversible. You then get $R_\theta x = 0 \iff  x = R_\theta^{-1} 0 =0$ which gives you $\ker R_\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple proof uses the fact that $L(\Bbb R^2)$ and $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ are isomorphic, where $L(\Bbb R^2)$ is the set of endomorphisms on $\Bbb R^2$.

Since a rotation $f$ is an isometry, $f(x) = 0 \implies x=0$, thus $\ker f = \{0\}$. It follows that $Im f = \Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is looking into your equations

$x_1 \cos(\theta) + x_2 (-\sin(\theta))=0$

$x_1 \sin(\theta) + x_2 (cos(\theta))=0$

Recurring to the second equation, which is clearer for this purpose, the $\cos(\theta)$and the $\sin(\theta)$ functions are generally non-zero, and they are orthogonal functions, in the sense of functional dot product, so the equallity holds if, and only if, each of the coefficients are zero. So $x_1=0$, and $x_2=0$.

Comment: Use LaTeX please. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/